# GLES 2.0 как реализовать GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH?

Tags: android, opengl, opengles, gles2.0

Как я понял в openGL 1.0 сглаживание полигонов делалось как-то так:

```
glEnable( GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH );
glHint( GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST );
glHint( GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST );
```

Я догадываюсь что в GLES 2.0 это делается как-то через шейдеры, но не могу нагуглить как.
Ожидаемый эффект как в Blendere по кнопке smooth - появляется сглаживаение (например сферы), без увеличения количества полигонов.

Comment: Давайте уточним, что в вашем понимании есть "сглаживание полигонов" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня как обычно, я всегда сам себе на вопросы отвечаю :)
поспал часик, нашел решение, до этого гуглил часа 4, никаких идей не было и ничего не понимал.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703432/why-does-my-opengl-phong-shader-behave-like-a-flat-shader

Решение простое,все дело в нормалях, при flat - они рассчитываются на поверхность, а при smooth - на вершину (тогда при передаче в фрагментный шейдер нормали между вершинами интерполируются, и получается что освещение гладкое). оказывается просто надо при выгрузке из Blender в режиме редактирования (Edit mode) включить

> mesh - vertex - smooth vertex
>
> mesh - faces - shade smooth

затем выгружать данные.
 И тогда обычный шейдер с попиксельным освещением отрисует сглаженный объект, 
 если кому интересно шейдеры брал отсюда:

http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-three-moving-to-per-fragment-lighting/

Comment: Вы путаете расчет освещения и антиалиасинг.

Comment: Да, я согласен. Просто у меня было действительно 2 проблемы,  которые давали эффект "угловатости модели" одна это отсутствие сглаживания совсем, а вторая - некорректный расчет нормалей для освещения. Причем я мультисемплинг то включил через изменение конфига, но эффекта ожидаемого не получил. https://code.google.com/p/gdc2011-android-opengl/source/browse/trunk/src/com/example/gdc11/MultisampleConfigChooser.java?r=2

Comment: Я в терминах то плаваю безусловно, и если кто-то мне пояснит про то что есть сглаживание полигонов и как оно делает в GLES 2.0 я вообще только за :) прям буду рад  - пишите...